# Jquery cancel button input placeholder text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I asked this question earlier, but asked without the proper info, here it goes again. What i need to happen is for the cancel button "list_btn_cancel" to close the popup activity and to replace what was imputed with the inputs placeholder.
This table is the input.

```
    <table  width="100%" style="line-height:0px" >
        <tr>
            <td><p>1.</p></td>
            <td><input name="activities_thoughts_1" id="activities_thoughts_1" type="text" style="width:345px;" placeholder="Type or click list button &gt;" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="thoughts_1"  class="list_btn ext_thoughts" value="List &gt;" /></td>
        </tr>

        </table>


    **this table is the popup**

    <div id="popup_activity" class="box_list">

          <div id="list_question_btn"></div></div>
        </div>
        <div id="activity_area_content" style="padding-bottom:5px;" >
    <form name="form1">   

    <table class="style2" width="100%">
        <tr><br />
          <td width="8%" align="right"><input name="thoughts_list" id="thoughts_list_0" class="thoughts_list" type="radio" value="It is just terrible that my child will not be a normal kid" /></td>

      </table>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div><table><td><a style="margin-left:290px" onclick="closeDialog('popup_activity');"><input type="button" id="thoughts_cancel"  class="list_btn list_btn_cancel" value="Cancel &gt;" placeholder="Type or click list button &gt;"  /></a></td>&nbsp;<td><a onclick="closeDialog('popup_activity');"><input style="margin-left:10px" type="button" id="close_thoughts"  class="list_btn list_btn_close" value="Close &gt;" /></a></td></table></div></div>

    **Here is the script**
    $('.list_btn').button();

    $('#popup_activity').css("display","none");
    $('#list_help').css("display","none");

    $('.ext_thoughts').click(function(){
        openDialog('popup_activity');
        btn_id= $(this).attr('id');
    });

    $('.thoughts_list').click(function(){
        ( $(this).attr('id'));
        $("#activities_" +btn_id).val($(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: If you already posted then you should be updating that question, not making a new one.
You also haven't said what you've tried / why it doesn't work.
_What have you tried?_

Comment: I dont really know what im doing, But I have tryed to replace the .val with placeholder, that didnt do anything.

Comment: Try cutting down the code you gave to the bare essentials - it's hard to see you're trying to do with 50 lines of code.

Comment: I currently have this, which just adds the buttons value, not the inputs placeholder. $('.list_btn_cancel').click(function(){ ( $(this).attr('id')); $("#activities_" +btn_id).val($(this).val()); });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay don't quite understand what you want but here is what i think you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
    { 
    $('.ext_thoughts').click(function(){
        $("#popup_activity").toggle();  
    });
    $('.list_btn_cancel').click(function(){
            $("#popup_activity").hide();
        $("#activities_thoughts_1").val('');
     }); 
    });
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
<input name="activities_thoughts_1" id="activities_thoughts_1" type="text" style="width:345px;" placeholder="Type or click list button " />
<br>
<input type="button" id="thoughts_1"  class="list_btn ext_thoughts" value="Show/Hide List" />
<input type="button" id="thoughts_cancel"  class="list_btn list_btn_cancel" value="Cancel" />
<br>


<div id="popup_activity" class="box_list" style="display:none;">
This is the pop up division         
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/aaaheatair/g9axT/)

Comment: Thanks guys, I am still very new to any type of programming language. This is exactly what I needed! $('.list_btn_cancel').click(function(){
            $("#popup_activity").hide();
        $("#activities_thoughts_1").val('');
     });

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to figure out exactly what you're trying to do from your question but if all you want is for the text input to revert to its placeholder text simply set its value to blank.

```
$("#activities_thoughts_1").val('');
```

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/arG5f/